# How to move to next line and enter insert mode at same indentation level in Vim

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

I am using VimIdea in IntelliJ.

How can move to the next line from *normal mode* and enter *insert mode* ***matching the indentation***.

While in normal mode, using `o` creates a new line and enters insert mode at the matching indentation level.

For example (`^` represents cursor position)

```
@Test
public void crea^teDirectory() {

}
```

Pressing `o` takes me to `^` and enter insert mode. But leaves unwanted already a present blank line.

```
@Test
public void createDirectory() {
    ^

}
```

However, I already have a blank line and I need to go to the blank line and enter insert mode matching indentation level.

Pressing `+i` takes me to the next line and enters insert mode but it takes me to the start of the line (column 0).

```
@Test
public void createDirectory() {
^
    }
```

Currently what I am doing to get the required behavior:

```
+ddO
```

Is there anything as short as `o`?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command `:set cindent`, you can use `cc` to change the current line and insert with indenting.

[:help C-indenting](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#C-indenting)